# Making a football standings from infinite match list input

Tags: java, oop

I have an assignment which I have to program that creates a standings table from match list input. I used the word "infinite" because input size is unknown so I have to create a program that works until there's no matches left. I created a football class for this(input contains 2 other sports and their own matches and teams indicating the sports type with first letter of the sport with "F, B, V" for example, they're only different in scoring part, so I though if I can make football work, I can make anything else work) that contains everything required in standings table, and methods for match results which looks like this:

```
public class Football {
    private int scoredGoals;
    private int receivedGoals;
    private String teamName;
    private int Score;
    private int wins;
    private int losses;
    private int MatchCount;
    private int draws;
    
    public void teamValues(String teamName, int Sgoals, int Rgoals) {
        this.teamName = teamName;
        this.scoredGoals = Sgoals;
        this.receivedGoals = Rgoals;
        
    }           

    public void matched() {
        MatchCount++;
    }
    
    public void winner() {
        wins++;
    }
    
    public void draw() {
        draws++;
    }
    
    public void loser() {
        losses++;
    }
    
    
    public void winScore() {
        Score += 3;
    }
    
    public void drawScore() {
        Score += 1;
    }
        
    
    public String showTeams() {
        return (teamName + "    " + MatchCount + "  " + wins + "    " + draws + "   " + losses + "  " + scoredGoals+":"+receivedGoals + "   " + Score);
    }
    
}
```

And in main class I'm calling  methods in if blocks to calculate wins, score, matches count etc. And main looks like this:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        
        
        
        File file = new File("input.txt");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(file);
        String fileString = "";
        Football teams[] = new Football[2];
        HashSet<String> teamsArray = new HashSet<String>();
        
        
        
        while(scan.hasNextLine()) {
            fileString = scan.nextLine();
            String[] match = fileString.split("\\t|:");
            
            if(match[0].equals("F")) {
                int team1score = Integer.valueOf(match[3].trim());
                int team2score = Integer.valueOf(match[4].trim());
                
                teams[0] = new Football();
                teams[0].teamValues(match[1], team1score, team2score);
                teams[1] = new Football();
                teams[1].teamValues(match[2], team2score, team1score);
                teams[0].matched();
                teams[1].matched();
                if(team1score>team2score) {
                    
                    teams[0].winner();
                    teams[1].loser();
                    
                    teams[0].winScore();
                }
                
                if(team1score==team2score) {
                    teams[0].draw();
                    teams[1].draw();
                    
                    teams[0].drawScore();
                    teams[1].drawScore();
                }
                
                if(team1score<team2score) {
                    teams[1].winner();
                    teams[0].loser();
                    
                    teams[1].winScore();
                }
            
            String team0 = teams[0].showTeams();
            String team1 = teams[1].showTeams();
            
            teamsArray.add(team0);
            teamsArray.add(team1);
            
        }   
    }
        scan.close();
    }   
}
```

Since the input is static, I used arrays to work around. My problem with my code is I cant find a way to store my teams without duplicates and the variables that comes within and update whenever that team has another match.

I tried;

- Storing them in a 2D string array but since the amount of teams is unknown I think it won't be a healthy way to approach to the problem.
- Storing them in a String[] array list, which ended up storing the adresses instead of the values of the teams.
- Set which I still use to check if at least the methods are working as intended.

It feels like I hit the wall with this program and I need to start over, so any kind of advice is appreciated.

Here's an example of input and output:

```
Input:
    Home Team       Guest Team         H : G
F   Manchester U.   Chelsea            2 : 2
F   Liverpool       Manchester City    3 : 2
F   Leicester City  Everton            1 : 3
V   Team A          Team B             3 : 0
F   Tottenham       Liverpool          3 : 1
B   Team B          Team A            90 : 96
F   West Ham        Manchester U.      2 : 1
F   Arsenal         Manchester City    0 : 2
F   Chelsea         Arsenal            3 : 3

Output: 
    Name          Matches Wins Draw Lose   Scored:Received Score
1.  Manchester U.   10     6    2    2         27:22        20
2.  Arsenal         10     6    2    2         25:24        20 
3.  Chelsea         10     5    3    2         28:20        18
4.  Liverpool       10     4    4    2         22:19        16
5.  Tottenham       10     4    4    2         22:21        16
```

There are teams with same scores, because calculating average of scored and received goals is another way to sort the teams.

Comment: Only restriction is that I have to create new .java files for each sports type and use them on my main.java other than that I'm allowed to do everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First some changes to the `Football` class:

- Override `equals` to be able to search the list
- Override `compareTo` for sorting
- Override `toString` instead of `showTeams`
- Create a constructor
- Combine most functions into `teamValues`

```
import java.util.Formatter;

public class Football implements Comparable<Football> {
    private int scoredGoals;
    private int receivedGoals;
    private String teamName;
    private int score;
    private int wins;
    private int losses;
    private int draws;
    private int matchCount;
    
    public int compareTo(Football f) {
        return score - f.score;
    }
    
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o == null) {
            return false;
        }
        else if (o instanceof Football) {
            return teamName.equals(((Football)o).teamName);
        }
        else if (o instanceof String) {
            return teamName.equals((String)o);
        }
        return false;
    }
    
    public Football(String teamName) {
        this.teamName = teamName;
    }
    
    public void teamValues(int scoredGoals, int receivedGoals) {
        this.scoredGoals += scoredGoals;
        this.receivedGoals += receivedGoals;
        matchCount++;
        if (scoredGoals < receivedGoals) {
            losses++;
        }
        else if (scoredGoals > receivedGoals) {
            wins++;
            score += 3;
        }
        else {
            draws++;
            score += 1;
        }
    }           

    public String toString() {
        return new Formatter().format("%-20s %3d %3d %3d %3d %3d:%-3d %d",
            teamName, matchCount, wins, draws, losses, scoredGoals, receivedGoals, score)
            .toString();
    } 
}
```

For the main program, you don't want to create a new team every time - only when a team is first encountered in the file. Put all the teams in a `List`. When parsing a new game, first try to find the team in the list. If it is not in there, add it.

```
List<Football> teamsArray = new ArrayList<>();
        
while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
    fileString = scan.nextLine();
    String[]match = fileString.split("\\t|:");

    if (match.length == 5 && match[0].equals("F")) {
        int team1score = Integer.valueOf(match[3].trim());
        int team2score = Integer.valueOf(match[4].trim());

        // Create a temp team to search the List
        Football team1 = new Football(match[1]);
        // Search the list
        if (!teamsArray.contains(team1)) {
            // Not in the list already. Add it
            teamsArray.add(team1);
        }
        else {
            // Already in the List. Use that one.
            team1 = teamsArray.get(teamsArray.indexOf(team1));
        }
        // Repeat for team 2
        Football team2 = new Football(match[2]);
        if (!teamsArray.contains(team2)) {
            teamsArray.add(team2);
        }
        else {
            team2 = teamsArray.get(teamsArray.indexOf(team2));
        }
        team1.teamValues(team1score, team2score);
        team2.teamValues(team2score, team1score);
    }
}
System.out.println("Name                   M   W   D   L   S:R   S");
// Sort and print
teamsArray
    .stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
    .forEach(t -> System.out.println(t));
```

Comment: I can't thank you enough for all the effort. I think key here is using formatter in football. I also improved my code after asking here creating the object creater method and optimising football methods. But I've just wanted some improvements on the duplicate part of my code not the whole assignment. Now I'm worried that people that taking my course will also copy paste this for their assignment. So can you delete your comment. I really appreciate the time and effort you put for me though. Thank you from the bottom of my heart.

Comment: I changed my mind I believe this will be very helpful for people having problems with object sorting. Thanks a ton again. I'd upvote thousand times if i could. :)

Comment: One of the goals with SO is not just helping the original person asking the question but with future visitors who might have similar question. Usually I don't add so much code but found it hard to explain without it.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that after finding answers to my questions from 4 5 years old questions :D

Comment: I'm trying to use comparator for sorting the teams with first score and then average of scores( scored - received) for the teams with same score. But I cant find a way to make it work. What should i update on your compareTo method in footballl class, Im using something very similar to that.

Comment: I fixed it changing compareTo method to this : 

public int compareTo(Football f) {
     if (score == f.score) {
   return average - f.average;
  }
     else
      return score - f.score;   
    }